# Add comments to solr document

Tags: solr

what would be the most native way, to add comments to documents in solr? I would like to add comments with some user_id, datetime and the actual comment.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to load them together with the document: Stringify the array of objects and store it in an additional field.

If you want to search the comments also you have to split the fields of the comments up and store the comment text in a searchable multivalued field.

Comment: there is no need to search, just "attaching" them to the document and retrieving together with a document in a query is enough.

Comment: Then add a simple text field "comments" to the document schema stringify the array and store the string in "comments". In JavaScript/node.js this would be done with JSON.stringify().

Answer (score 1):

depending on your needs, if you wanted to query on the comments (so sort of maintaining the 1 Doc ---> N comments relationship in a more DB-like way) you might want to use [block join](http://blog.griddynamics.com/2013/09/solr-block-join-support.html) too. Be aware of its limitations though

Comment: and this can be done with solr only, no db needed to save comments? will check link now, thx